# Dynamically create conditionals from dynamic dataset in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My geolocation mobile app runs based on some hard coded conditionals like so...

```
function checkTime(hms){
        // for example a day (day 0 == Sun) between 06:00 and 23:45
        if( (today === 1 || today === 2 || today === 3 || today === 4) && hms > "09:00:00" && hms < "15:40:00") {
                ajax_post(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, position.coords.accuracy, position.coords.speed, position.timestamp);
        }
        else if( today === 5 && hms > "13:00:00" && hms < "13:40:00") {
                ajax_post(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, position.coords.accuracy, position.coords.speed, position.timestamp);
        }
        else {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Data not scheduled to be posted to the server yet";
        }
}
```

I've now made a form to get the set the times. The times are stored in html5's `localStorage` in an object like so...

```
var timeDb = {
    mon:[],
    tue:[{start:"21:00",end:"23:00"},{start:"23:00",end:"22:30"}],
    wed:[],
    thu:[],
    fri:[],
    sat:[{start:"11:00",end:"22:15"}],
    sun:[]
}
```

My question is, as the above is dynamic, how to I dynamically create the conditionals for the above when `timeDb` is updated by the user? I'm only working with JavaScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array for the day number to day string conversion and access `timeDB` with this day name and check if one item is in the scheduled time.

```js
function checkTime(today, hms) {
    var numberToDay = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
    if (timeDb[numberToDay[today]].some(t => t.start >= hms && hms <= t.end)) {
        //ajax_post
        return true;
    } else {
        // document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Data not scheduled to be posted to the server yet";
        return false;
    }
}

var timeDb = { mon: [], tue: [{ start: "21:00", end: "23:00" }, { start: "23:00", end: "22:30" }], wed: [], thu: [], fri: [], sat: [{ start: "11:00", end: "22:15" }], sun: [] };

console.log(checkTime(0, '00:00')); // false
console.log(checkTime(1, '22:00')); // true
```

Comment: Wow, this is great, thanks. I had never heard of `.some`, but that will change!

Comment: [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is an exists quantifier for array and very handy in tool of checking an array with conditions.

Comment: I was just implementing this today, and changed a couple of things. If anyone was having trouble with the above example, try starting the `numberToDay` on `sun`, and switching the first `hms` condition like so `hms >= t.start`.